# compute sum of columns in a nested list in R

Tags: r

How do we do column sums on elements of nested lists. I have a nested list of 10  each containing a sublist of 50 elements which are matrices with 4 columns with differing number of rows. Here is a simpler example. I need to add the columns across the lists. I need a vector of colsums.ll<-c(26, 66, 106, 146). I tried to do do.call("rbind",ll) to collapse the list into 1 dataframe and then apply colSums but was not successful.

```
    l1<-matrix(c(1:8),nrow=2)
    l2<-matrix(c(1:16),nrow=4)
    l<-list(l1,l2)
    ll<-list(l,l)
     ll
    [[1]]
   [[1]][[1]]
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]    1    3    5    7
  [2,]    2    4    6    8

   [[1]][[2]]
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    1    5    9   13
    [2,]    2    6   10   14
    [3,]    3    7   11   15
    [4,]    4    8   12   16


    [[2]]
    [[2]][[1]]
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    1    3    5    7
    [2,]    2    4    6    8

    [[2]][[2]]
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    1    5    9   13
    [2,]    2    6   10   14
    [3,]    3    7   11   15
    [4,]    4    8   12   16
```

Comment: `lapply(unlist(ll, recursive = FALSE), colSums)` OR `lapply(lapply(rapply(ll, enquote, how="unlist"), eval), colSums)`

Comment: Thanks. But that just sums first columns of each submatrix. I need a sum of first column of all the elements of the list. In the above case the answer should be c(26, 66, 106, 146).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways:

**1)** Flatten the first level of ll, take the column sums and then take the row sums of the result:

```
rowSums(sapply(do.call(c, ll), colSums))
## [1]  26  66 106 146
```

**2)** Another way is after flattening then `rbind` all the matrices together and then take `colSums` of that.  Note that in contrast to (1) this one has no `sapply` or `lapply`.

```
colSums(do.call(rbind, do.call(c, ll)))
## [1]  26  66 106 146
```

**3)** The above do not use any packages but could be translated to use magrittr like this where the first pipeline corresponds to (1) and the second to (2)

```
library(magrittr)

ll %>% do.call(what = c) %>% sapply(colSums) %>% rowSums
## [1]  26  66 106 146

ll %>% do.call(what = c) %>% do.call(what = rbind) %>% colSums
## [1]  26  66 106 146
```

Answer (score 1):

```
colSums(do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(rapply(ll, enquote, how="unlist"), eval), colSums)))
[1]  26  66 106 146
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a purrr option:

```
library(purrr)

ll %>% flatten() %>%    # reduce depth to one level
    map(colSums) %>%    # get column sums of each element
    reduce(`+`)         # add respective colSums
#> [1]  26  66 106 146
```

or reduce it to a single matrix first:

```
ll %>% flatten() %>% reduce(rbind) %>% colSums()
```

or use `invoke` instead of `reduce`, which saves calls at the cost of slightly-less-beautiful syntax:

```
ll %>% flatten() %>% invoke(rbind, .) %>% colSums()
```

All return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I like `Reduce` in base R, so you could do:

```
Reduce("+", lapply(Reduce(c, ll), colSums))
# [1]  26  66 106 146
```

---

**BENCHMARKING**

```
set.seed(100)
l1 <- matrix(sample(100, 100000, replace = TRUE),ncol=1000)
l2 <- matrix(sample(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE),ncol=1000)
l <- list(l1,l2)
ll <- rep(list(l), 100)
str(ll)
# List of 100
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ : int [1:100, 1:1000] 31 26 56 6 47 49 82 38 55 18 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:1000, 1:1000] 45 22 77 7 85 32 80 71 52 38 ...
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ : int [1:100, 1:1000] 31 26 56 6 47 49 82 38 55 18 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:1000, 1:1000] 45 22 77 7 85 32 80 71 52 38 ...
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ : int [1:100, 1:1000] 31 26 56 6 47 49 82 38 55 18 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:1000, 1:1000] 45 22 77 7 85 32 80 71 52 38 ...
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ : int [1:100, 1:1000] 31 26 56 6 47 49 82 38 55 18 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:1000, 1:1000] 45 22 77 7 85 32 80 71 52 38 ...
```

---

```
library(purrr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(magrittr)

f_G.Grothendieck1 <- function(ll) rowSums(sapply(do.call(c, ll), colSums)) 
f_G.Grothendieck2 <- function(ll) colSums(do.call(rbind, do.call(c, ll)))
f_G.Grothendieck3 <- function(ll) 
    ll %>% do.call(what = c) %>% sapply(colSums) %>% rowSums
f_G.Grothendieck4 <- function(ll) 
    ll %>% do.call(what = c) %>% do.call(what = rbind) %>% colSums
f_d.b <- function(ll) 
  colSums(do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(rapply(ll, enquote, how="unlist"), eval), colSums)))
f_alistaire1 <- function(ll) ll %>% flatten() %>%  map(colSums) %>%  reduce(`+`)
f_alistaire2 <- function(ll) ll %>% flatten() %>% invoke(rbind, .) %>% colSums()
f_989 <- function(ll) Reduce("+", lapply(Reduce(c, ll), colSums))

r <- f_G.Grothendieck1(ll)
# [1] TRUE
all(r == f_G.Grothendieck2(ll))
# [1] TRUE
all(r == f_G.Grothendieck3(ll))
# [1] TRUE
all(r == f_G.Grothendieck4(ll))
# [1] TRUE
all(r == f_d.b(ll))
# [1] TRUE
all(r == f_alistaire1(ll))
# [1] TRUE
all(r == f_alistaire2(ll))
# [1] TRUE
all(r == f_989(ll))
# [1] TRUE
res <- microbenchmark(
f_G.Grothendieck1(ll), f_G.Grothendieck2(ll), f_G.Grothendieck3(ll), 
f_G.Grothendieck4(ll), f_d.b(ll), f_alistaire1(ll), f_alistaire2(ll), f_989(ll))
```

---

```
print(res, order="mean")
    # Unit: milliseconds
                      # expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
                 # f_989(ll)   84.67007   87.05084   87.50351   87.70766   88.25692   91.12715   100
          # f_alistaire1(ll)   85.00209   87.35116   87.83935   87.91318   88.32242   98.69927   100
                 # f_d.b(ll)   85.15563   87.74943   88.01660   88.23258   88.72280   89.89943   100
     # f_G.Grothendieck1(ll)   85.38729   87.77707   88.40864   88.45328   89.03604  100.78963   100
     # f_G.Grothendieck3(ll)   85.85933   87.85805   88.69445   88.68118   89.28618  104.93881   100
     # f_G.Grothendieck4(ll) 1150.27718 1200.80601 1205.76164 1206.48442 1211.72250 1310.64802   100
          # f_alistaire2(ll) 1178.14509 1202.61153 1207.05208 1205.89009 1211.49820 1325.72315   100
     # f_G.Grothendieck2(ll) 1177.02283 1204.55166 1210.40954 1208.95338 1213.82218 1278.82715   100
```

Comment: With tiny data your benchmark is mainly capturing the overhead of the pipe, which you can see if you compare the same calls nested and piped, like Gabor's 1/3 and 2/4. It would make more sense to benchmark on data large enough to see what the differences will be at scale.

Comment: @alistaire updated. I did not include your second solution cause its really time consuming.

Comment: Interesting, the memory allocation of combining matrices is way more of a killer than calling `colSums` a lot more times.